# ZFS folder duplication and deletion

Tags: directory, ubuntu-16.04, directory-structure, zfs

I had a folder which was encrypted by `encfs`. It was in an `ext4` partition. I decided to move it into another folder, because I had not enough space in that partition. The new partition was a compression-enabled `zfs` partition on another hard disk. During the move along with the destination folder 'td', another folder '.shutdowntd' was also created. I don't know why. I didn't created it. Maybe `zfs` itself created it. Maybe `encfs` manager did it. Last night I looked into it. I saw that the number of files in both directories is the same. I saw that for any file in the directory 'td' there is a file in directory '.shutdowntd'. File sizes were not exactly the same, but were nearly the same. When I deleted a file in one of them, the corresponding file in the other directory was also deleted! The names in the directory '.shutdowntd' were different and seemed to be hash-coded. My computer was on during the night. Today, I saw that the folder 'td' was removed and a zero-byte file with the same name was created! I restarted Ubuntu (16.04). Now I see that the file is changed back to a folder with the same name ('td') with no content. But the folder '.shutdowntd' still exists with the files in it. I can't justify this behavior and don't know why it happened. Essentially why '.shutdowntd' is created? Why 'td's' content is emptied?! How can I recover it? What's happening?!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: This does not sound like anything ZFS would do. Compression and deduplication works at the block level, you do not see any files. I suggest to reformat your question to make it more clear and better to read, and then ask it again at superuser.com